# atan(-M_PI_2) is not returing -90 º

Tags: c++, math

I have a problem calculating atan in cpp. M_PI is already declared as 3.14159....

My code is:

```
double distanceNormalized = 1;// set constant con check value
double angle = atan(distanceNormalized * (-M_PI_2)); // atan(-PI/2) must be -1 in rad

stringstream ss;
ss  << " Angle: " << angle*180/M_PI;
cout << ss << endl;
```

But in log I get:

```
Angle: -57.5184
```

Reference say [admit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan/) [-pi/2,+pi/2] radians.
What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the correct output.

`-57.5184` degrees is equivalent to `-1 rad` if you assume `π = 3.14`. `angle` is in fact `-1 rad` here. You're converting it to degrees by multiplying it by `180` and dividing by `π`.

Comment: Pi is at least 3.14159 printing it, is not only 3.14

Comment: Still the same concept. I usually define such constants to 6 or 7 digits of precision so I can use them in operations with floats without overflowing. (Even though I still use the `double` type pretty much everywhere ;v)

Comment: Well, you are right, I was specting another result, M_PI_2 * atan(). Thanks

Comment: @Walter `-1*180/Pi=-57.5184` google says -57.2957, using Pi as 3.14 gives -57.3248. To get -57.5184 you have to use pi as 3.13.Where does that inaccuracy come in?

Comment: I think he used 3.14159 instead of 3.14 :o